# Rendering screen with modals takes long time

Tags: react-native, react-native-modal

I'm developing an application, and one screen in the app has many modals (let say 7-8 modals) which is used to show up information or enter data. The issue is, when I navigate to this screen, it's always take a long time (2-3 seconds) to render the screen. The screen was smooth and render fast before I put those modals on it. I guess it's because the screen has to render all modals, even though they're not yet displaying. Is it true? How can I solve this issue.

Comment: Your app has performance issues because you use the modals everywhere. I think you should put your modals in App.js and make them global maybe with redux.

Comment: @ridvanaltun wow, this is the first time I see a suggestion like your. Maybe it works. But is this a best practice?